# How to ignore records in a MongoDB index based on an attribute condition

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I want to query for a collection based on the value of a count being greater than 0.  For example, I want to optimize a query where I get all "dealerships" with a "car_count" greater than 0.  My first instinct was to index based on car count in descending order.  Since we'll never show more than 100 dealerships or some reasonable number, this will perform well.  However, I think the index could be optimized because there is no reason for dealerships with a "car_count" = 0 to be in that index in the first place.  We're wasting RAM.  Just FYI - not actually doing this for dealerships so it's entirely possible that there will be a non-trivial amount of "dealerships" with a "car_count" = 0.  How can I change the following index to ignore "dealerships" with a "car_count" = 0:

```
db.dealerships.ensureIndex({"car_count":-1})
```

Will the solution make writes much more inefficient than my existing index?

Comment: You can create create a sparse index (http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-sparse%3Atrue) , that does not include any documents that do not have a given field. So if you wanted to have an index on only dealerships that have a car count > 0 , you could just not include a car_count field on dealerships without any cars. Then you could create the following index : db.dealerships.ensureIndex( {"car_count" : -1 }, {sparse : true} ). This might not work for every application, but could be helpful for excluding documents that have a count of 0 for a given field.

Comment: Ok, I'm actually already aware of that solution and it seems like a good one.  Just wondering if there was another way